# Why is this Brush with a #00FFFFFF value not equal to Brushes.Transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm retrieving a list of Brushes via reflection from another class. I want to make sure that some Brush in this List is *not* Transparent (`#00FFFFFF`).
However, comparing it with `Brushes.Transparent` returns false even though the value is in fact `#00FFFFFF`.

```
var brushes = GetListOfBrushes();
var brush = brushes.First(c => c != Brushes.Transparent);    
Console.WriteLine(brush); // Prints "#00FFFFFF"
```

The only reliable way in this case is to check its string representation if it starts with `#00" which feels hacky.

In the example screenshot below the Brush returned from the `First()` call matches the predicate although it should not:

[image]

Comment: The SolidColorBrush class does not override Equals + GetHashCode.  Which isn't the great mystery, it is rather debatable if 0x00ffffff is more or less transparent than, say, 0x00ff0000.  You'll have to set your own rule, checking the alpha is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you compare brushes you probably want to do `Cast<SolidColorBrush>()` or do some pre-filtering if they aren't all solid colors (i.e. not `Transparent` by default).

You then can compare the `brush.Color` with `Brushes.Transparent.Color`.

Answer (score 4):

From your string representation I infer that you use `System.Windows.Media.Brush` and not `System.Drawing.Brush`.

`System.Windows.Media.Brush` has not implemented an own version of `Equals()`. So your comparsion

```
c != Brushes.Transparent
```

only compares for **reference equality** but not for equal values. One solution would be to compare the opacities:

```
var brush = brushes.First(c => c.Opacity != Brushes.Transparent.Opacity);
```

But maybe you will want to compare some more properties, depending on your needs or how you want to identify that special brush.

Comment: That will also catch the no-hit-test transparent (`#00000000`) though, would just compare `Color`.

Comment: @H.B. I'm not so experienced in wpf and just could not find a `Color` property in `System.Windows.Media.Brush`.

Comment: It only exists for `SolidColorBrush`, you need to cast the brushes (as explained in my answer).

Comment: The opacity of the brush is 1, even though the alpha is 00.