# LinearGradientBrush Transparency Inconsistency in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linear-gradients

I'm toying with a third party color picker. In this picker, to make the spectrum picker region, the author has used three overlaid regions; one with a solid color fill of the chosen hue, one on top of that with a horizontal gradient from white to transparent, and one overlaid on that with a vertical gradient from transparent to black.

While fiddling, I noticed that WPF exhibits inconsistent behavior regarding completely transparent colors depending on the color I have defined in hex for the transparent GradientStop. I noticed this with `#00******` (any color with alpha at 0) as a value for the background LinearGradientBrush's GradientStop Color property. It appears that the hex coded transparent color is actually ever so slightly visible, and tinted to match its color despite the alpha value of 0.

Here is the expected behavior using `#00000000`; a nice smooth gradient:

[image: Linear Gradient]

..and here is the behavior using Transparent; where the gradient seems to not be linear anymore, but biased towards the base.

[image: Non-linear Gradient]

(This same behavior is exhibited should I do the same to the white gradient behind, but I haven't to make it easy to tell the difference.)

Here's the code for reference.

```
                    <Grid x:Name="BlackGradient">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0, 0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
```

(Change Transparent to a transparent hex color to see the effect in action, e.g. `#00000000`.)

Having read the MSDN docs for Brushes.Transparent, Microsoft indicates that Transparent resolves to `#00FFFFFF`, and this is indeed what tipped me off about the color being ever so slightly visible after I tried various transparent hex colors.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.transparent(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the solid fill color that has a hexadecimal value of #00FFFFFF.

It's not really a problem per-se, but I am curious as to why this is. Does anyone have any idea why these cases are treated differently?

Comment: FWIW, the unanswered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290403/transparent-gradientstop-in-silverlight-is-not-exactly-transparent seems to pertain to the same behavior.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223479/why-is-this-brush-with-a-00ffffff-value-not-equal-to-brushes-transparent

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's related, sorry. This seems to be a difference in rendering/implementation behavior seemingly isolated to the LinerGradientBrush, whereas your linked question pertains to how C# handles equality behavior for System.Windows.Media.Color object types.
I've edited the title to make the issue a bit clearer.

Comment: If I replace `<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>` with `<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>`, it looks exactly the same. Of course an increasingly transparent white creates a different result than an increasingly transparent black (or any other color). So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Ah, correct (transparent resolves to that after all). Replacing `#00FFFFFF` with `#00000000` will give you the most dramatic difference. That point was diluted as I refined the question; will edit question accordingly, my mistake.